# Yii Website Login through Android AsyncTask

Tags: android, authentication, yii, web

I am working on a login module for Our Yii website through Android, I have done and could post the username and password to the login url localhost/telemac/index.php/user/auth and it returns the html code for logged in page. I set a key to make sure that the logged in user is a valid user by writing this line

```
String ret = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
```

which returns the response "OK"and I tried this as well

```
String ret = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

which returns 200 as the response code. Even if a wrong user logs in, it returns the same response "OK" and 200 respectively. I spent a lot of time on this. could not get a right solution. Plz help me to fix this

Comment: Does your website return a valid webpage with an error message on an invalid login? Is the HTTP status code set to 200 on an invalid login (when you view the reply in curl for example)?

Answer (score 0):

Giving status code `200` response code is symbol of successful calling of your url.

If your url executes even if you pass wrong/correct data then you can get `200` status code.
you have to get the response from the web service in the form of xml/json and then you can parse it. for more information you can see [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/&ei=6rQVU5yjEIq0rAec7oGIAg&usg=AFQjCNE5qMM8hgUE5uR2bXz0Lx0qFKMz6A&sig2=4yHjP6_ijCKaMOlPWRl_xg)

Comment: I already referred this tutorial, he uses his own api document I want to know about json response from Yii because it is a cookie based authentication

Comment: I think they will provide the webservices for that framework right..you can use them.

Comment: Yes extensions are available but doen't suite for our requirements just now  I've some key points so let me go through that. Thanks